# I2C slave NACK with multiple slaves

Tags: vhdl, i2c

Hi I'm  writing an VHDL  slave interface, I've a doubt on I2C standard with address slave ID.
For example the first slave has address 0x5A , the second address 0x5B
Master starts operation with adresses 0x5A so slave responds with ack , but slave b , respond with a nack or simply goes to idle state because addresses not match and do nothing ?
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since NACK does not drive SDA low, you cannot differentiate between NACK and "do nothing" from an outer view.

It depends on your requirement on the logic, whether you go into idle state or not.

The probably good solution is to go into the state that waits for the next start condition. If this is your idle state, it is fine.